# Bootstrap Modal in a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal within `display: table-cell;` container, but when the modal is provoked, it's not in full screen, but instead fits inside the `div`. How do I make it so that it fits full screen? I've been struggling with this problem for a long time, so someone please help me!

```css
.action-delete-btn {
    text-align: center !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    float:right;
    top:10px;
}

.action-delete-btn {
    display:none;
}

.action-delete-btn {
    right:130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bc33a16514.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-wrap" id="word-list-container">
    <button class="btn btn-danger rounded-circle action-delete-btn" id="delete-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeletionModal">
         <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="modal" id="confirmDeletionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenteredLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenteredLabel">Are you sure you want to delete this?</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Yes, delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Fw8.png)

Comment: Please show some sample code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Okay, I added the sample code

Comment: I have multiple containers in my code, and the problem is that the modal only shows up within the small div within the container. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code into the CSS file

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```